# How to reanimate div with jquery after using css keyframe animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to have a div appear on page load using a css keyframe to animate a div from 0 to 0.7. Then, I want the user to be able to mouse over this div and have its opacity animate from 0.7 to 1 and back to 0.7 when they mouse off of it. The mouse over animations are being handled by my jquery code. The problem is, it seems like I can only have one or the other. Is this possible to do?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Test Web Site 1 Style Sheet.css"></link>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css"></link>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Test Web Site 1.js"></script>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body id = "main">
        <div class = "titleBar animated fadeInTranslucent">
            <p class = "title">Title</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: url('images/Background Official.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.title {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 50pt;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.titleBar {
  height: 9%;
  width: 34%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -42.5px;
  margin-left: -310px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInTranslucent {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 0.7;}
}

@keyframes fadeInTranslucent {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 0.7;}
}

.fadeInTranslucent {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInTranslucent;
    animation-name: fadeInTranslucent;
}
```

animate.css excerpt (to explain animated class)

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
          animation-duration: .5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
          animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".titleBar").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".titleBar").stop().animate({opacity:1},400);
    });
    $(".titleBar").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".titleBar").stop().animate({opacity:0.7},400);
    });
});
```

In the div class = "titleBar animated fadeInTranslucent" part of my code, if you remove the "animated" and "fadeInTranslucent" classes, the jQuery part works. Otherwise, the jQuery is non-responsive and the keyframes work.

Comment: maybe i should ask which broser u use?

Comment: @micha I use firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.fadeInTranslucent {
 animation-name: fadeInTranslucent;
 -webkit-animation-name: fadeInTranslucent;
 -moz-animation-name: fadeInTranslucent;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
 -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
 -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/uFJbT8QbDf0q6fZcnJIV?p=preview

Comment: Never mind, I'm an idiot. I copy/pasted the entirety of all three docs and it worked! Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: On top of your change, I also found that I had to delete the .animated class from the classes assigned to the div. So the class section of the div should only read: class = "titleBar fadeInTranslucent"

Answer (score 0):

Do you not need periods before these class names? Like so:

```
@-webkit-keyframes .fadeInTranslucent {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 0.7;}
}

@keyframes .fadeInTranslucent {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 0.7;}
}
```

Comment: Apparently not since it works fine without them. I'm no expert but it works without it in mine and the famous animate.css doesn't have them either. The problem is getting jquery and css keyframes to both work with one div

Answer (score 0):

Check for the animation on the class to be done in your JQuery ready function and remove the animate class from the div

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".titleBar" ).one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(".titleBar").removeClass('animated fadeInTranslucent');   

    });
    $(".titleBar").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".titleBar").stop().animate({opacity:1},400);
    });
    $(".titleBar").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".titleBar").stop().animate({opacity:0.7},400);
    });
});
```